# Cannot determine build data storage root for project error IntelliJ Android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, build

I am trying to build an android application I coded, and I get the following error:

```
Error:build: Cannot determine build data storage root for project /Users/Flo/Programming/Android/workspace/<ProjectName>
```

I have marked `src` and `gen` as `source folders`, and `res` as `resource folder`.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should build a project(just as the workspace in Eclipse) first, it will generate a .idea directory. And then build a module(as the project in Eclipse) under that project. Finally, you can run your app successfully.

Answer (score 14):

I deleted the .idea folder and the .iml file then i reimported the project in Intellij and it worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you! 'Spent like 20 minutes looking everywhere. 
Little caveat was that I had to set the module JDK back to the correct one even though it's set in maven. :/ (So look out for that)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The problem was that the project directory and files were created under the root user, but IntelliJ was running as my own user, so IntelliJ could not create the necessary files. The solution was to run

```
chown -R myusername projectfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

In intellij I invalidated the cache and restarted. Worked fine